# Optimal ssl_bump configuration for whitelisted squid proxy

Tags: proxy, redhat, squid

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days now trying to get a whitelisted squid proxy to work. This is the first time working with squid 4.11 and don't remember having so many issues getting this to work in the past with older versions. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

So quick overview, I'm configuring this as a traditional forward proxy where you must explicitly say you want to use the proxy as opposed to an intercept (that is the next step if I can get this to work. I would ideally like the proxy to support both scenarios if possible).

The issue: when I curl to a website specifying the proxy, I get the following error:

```html
<pre>(71) Protocol error (TLS code: SQUID_ERR_SSL_HANDSHAKE)</pre>
<p>Handshake with SSL server failed: error:1425F175:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:inappropriate fallback</p>
```

Trawling through google, this is the closest I could see to the issue I am having:

http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-ssl-choose-client-version-inappropriate-fallback-on-some-sites-when-using-TLS1-2-td4688258.html

This mentioned potential issues with the ciphers and suggested some workarounds, but they were unsuccessful and it didn't appear this case was ever resolved.

Now this is where it gets interesting. Some more investigation, I noticed the following. If I did say a straight curl to google as follows:

```html
curl -k -v https://www.google.com --proxy 10.196.0.13:3128
```

Cipher Suite is:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

And error is

```html
<pre>(71) Protocol error (TLS code: SQUID_ERR_SSL_HANDSHAKE)</pre>
<p>Handshake with SSL server failed: error:1425F175:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:inappropriate fallback</p>
```

Now if I add in the following parameters to control min / max versions of TLS

```
curl -k -v https://www.google.com --proxy 10.196.0.13:3128 --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.3
```

Cipher Suite is:

```
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

And I get a successful 200 response along with the contents of the web page. I have tested this on a number of sites and the results are also successful.

So I guess the question, is this a simple case of adding in the correct allowed ciphers into the squid configuration to ensure these ciphers which are causing issues are disallowed? Or am I way off?

Here is a condensed squid config along with my attempts to control the ciphers which so far have had no effect

```squid
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid                           #Core Dump Location
cache deny all                                          #Cache Deny
#dns_v4_first on

#Enabled Services
#http_port 3128
http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB \
   cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.crt \
   key=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.key \
   cafile=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem

tls_outgoing_options \
   min-version=1.2 \
   options=NO_SSLv3,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE \
   cipher=SHA256,AES128

#Mandatory Deny
http_access deny !Safe_ports            #Deny unsafe ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports     #Deny CONNECT whre not over SSL Port

#Allow Manager Local Only
http_access allow localhost manager     #Allow manager where local
http_access deny manager                #Deny manager all other times

#Allow localhost and localnet ACLs
http_access allow localnet      #Allow localnet ACLs
http_access allow localhost     #Allow localhost

#Allow Whitelisted URLs everything else
http_access allow allowed_http_sites            
http_access allow SSL_ports                     
ssl_bump peek step1 all                         
ssl_bump peek step2 allowed_https_sites         
ssl_bump splice step3 allowed_https_sites       
ssl_bump terminate step2 all                    

#Deny everything else
http_access deny all    #Deny All
```

Comment: Did you install squid from source or from repository??

Comment: From a repository. Base OS is Redhat 8. Not my first choice, but kind of what we are stuck with

Comment: After further investigation, we have tried with a number of different OS's for the client. This issue only happens when using Redhat 7.x as the client. Redhat 8, Ubuntu, no issues so far